# To have something done

Tags: grammar, non-native-english, sounds

I have commentaries which should be sent to a server. After doing it, I'll say:

> I have got all the commentaries sent.

Does my sentence sound natural?

Comment: Welcome to [english.se]. Please limit yourself to questions on which you have done prior research, and include the results of your research in the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `Have got ... sent` is incorrect grammer

*I have sent all the commentaries* or *I have finished sending all...* are better.

Please note that *I have gotten bigger* is acceptable US English. I have a difficult time finding a source that explains exactly why I object to the usage of got AND gotten with **sent**
I am pretty sure it belongs to the 
*I sent it/I did send it* rule of did+infinitive

Comment: thank you. Unfortunately, I cannot vote up now 'cause I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: No problem. You can likely still accept the answer which is done by clicking the tick that appears next to the answer to the left

Comment: I believe *"I have gotten all the commentaries sent,"* would be seen as perfectly fine, albeit somewhat informal, by most Americans. (There are some grammar police who would object.) It sounds perfectly natural to me. The past participle *got* rather than *gotten* is used in the U.K., but I don't know how the sentence would be viewed by native British speakers.

Comment: Right. Gotten sent I can accept - got sent sounds like Cockney to me. Did you vote me down by the way?

Comment: I was the downvoter. Not only do I disagree with you, but you also didn't explain **why** it's not grammatical for British speakers (for American speakers, you need to use *gotten* instead).

Comment: Better now, or do I have to find the actual dictionary that shows it? I am no complaining about got/gotten but got sent/gotten sent

Comment: Much better. I still think it's grammatical, but at least now your answer gives some reasoning.